# Why no executables created after successful project build in Eclipse IDE : C program?

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

I have installed Eclipse IDE newly, and set up include path variables in my new C project. Then I wrote a simple helloworld program, and build the project. The build project is successful, with 0 warnings and 0 errors, but no .exe or .out files are created. As a result, when I am trying to run the program, it is giving error 'program file does not exist'.

[image]

What can be the problem?

Eclipse output from build (Trie.c is another program I built in the same package):

```
19:42:22 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project 
Datastructure ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc "-IC:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.5.2\\include\\ssp" "- 
IC:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.5.2\\include" "-IC:\\MinGW\\include" "- 
IC:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.5.2\\include-fixed" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c - 
fmessage-length=0 -o Trie.o "..\\Trie.c" 

19:42:22 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 158ms)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a full copy-paste, *as text*, of the build output.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: No build output is created at all, only .c file is present in the project folder.

Comment: In the bottom of the image there a window where Eclipse shows the command it uses to build, *that* is the build output. Please copy-paste it into the question.

Comment: The `gcc` command shown in the output window specifically requests that an object file be compiled and *not* linked.  That's exactly what you see.  The reason Eclipse does not go on to build an executable is unclear, but it's surely a matter of the configuration of your project and / or the specifics of which control you used in the IDE to build the project.